# Different resource usage when using a LIMIT and SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and without?

Tags: sql, resources

Is there a difference in resource usage if I write an SQL with a LIMIT and SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and without it?
Like

```
SELECT id FROM table;
```

or

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
```

So in the first one I get all the IDs, so I have to go through the whole database, to get the information but on the second one I only get 10 IDs but I need to go through the whole database to get my row count.